# create a dict by spliting a string in an ordered dict

Tags: python

I have an ordered dict that represent field definition ie Name, type, width, precision

it looks like this:

```
 OrderedDict([(u'CODE_MUN', 'str:8'), (u'CODE_DR_AN', 'str:8'),
 (u'AREA', 'float:31.2'), (u'PERIMETER', 'float:31.4')])
```

I would like to create a dict for each item that would be like this:

`{'name' : 'CODE_MUN', 'type': 'str', 'width': 8, 'precision':0}`  for fields without precision

and

`{'name' : 'AREA', 'type': 'float', 'width': 31, 'precision':2 }` for fiels with precision

```
for keys, values in fieldsDict.iteritems():
   dict = {}
   dict['name'] = keys
   props = re.split(':.', values)
   dict['type'] = props[0]
   dict['width'] = props[1]
   dict['precision'] = props[2]
```

of course I have index error when there is no precision defined. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: you can use a `try-except` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a try-except block.

```
for keys, values in fieldsDict.iteritems():
    dict = {}
    dict['name'] = keys
    props = re.split(':.', values)
    dict['type'] = props[0]
    dict['width'] = props[1]

    try:
        dict['precision'] = props[2]
    except IndexError:
        dict['precision'] = 0
```

You could also test for length using an if-else block. The methods are pretty close and I doubt this is a situation where it really matters, but for more on asking [forgiveness](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp) vs [permission](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-lbyl) you can see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing).

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `precision` is there or not.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

fieldsDict = OrderedDict([(u'CODE_MUN', 'str:8'), (u'CODE_DR_AN', 'str:8'),
 (u'AREA', 'float:31.2'), (u'PERIMETER', 'float:31.4')])

for keys, values in fieldsDict.iteritems():
   dict = {}
   dict['name'] = keys
   props = re.split(':.', values)
   dict['type'] = props[0]
   dict['width'] = props[1]
   if len(props) == 3:
       dict['precision'] = props[2]
   else:
       dict['precision'] = 0
   print dict
```

This might be help